# Small word game, removing duplicates

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am making a words matching game where I get a random word. For example: "duck"

I than converting the string to a string array,

Then I create 3 buttons for each character  - except 1 character that will be scrambled with other characters. So, the child drags it to the correct order.

Gameplay example:

The child has a word, "turtle", the word that appears is "t(_)rtle". After that, he has a place where he has a lot of characters, ie: "a","t","q","u"(correct one). Then he drags the word to the correct place.

Well, I managed to get this working, but only with 1 character,

In a for loop, I do this:

```
string[] stringArray = CMath.CharArrayToStringArray(getName().ToCharArray());
string randChar = getName().ToCharArray()[(CMath.randomIntBetween(0, getName().Length - 1))].ToString();

//create chars, if the char is the random character, skip its creation and store it to create it later on the place where the child can drag the words.
for (int i = 0; i < getName().Length; i++)
{
    if (stringArray[i] != randChar)
    {
        CCharacter aChar = new CCharacter(stringArray[i], (110) + 100 * i, 750, CCharacter.TYPE_GREEN);
        aChar.setInactive(true);
        mCharList.Add(aChar);
    }
}
```

This results in the following problem:

What does happen if you have a word that has repeated characters? ie:"characters";  you have 2 C's, 2 A's, 2 R's,...

If I use the code above it will leave blank spaces, but the point is, it shouldn't be : "ch(*)r(*)cters".
It should be : "ch(_)racters"

Image example:

[image]

Comment: Try building a check to see how many characters are left out. If one char has been left out, set a bool to true. Then just add all remaining char's if the bool is true. Just a brainfart.

Comment: This question is incredibly unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a loop just find the first occurence of the random character:

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(stringArray, randChar);
if(index > -1){
   stringArray[index] = "_";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just place

```
break;
```

in the end of your if statement:

```
    if (stringArray[i] != randChar)
    {
        CCharacter aChar = new CCharacter(stringArray[i], (110) + 100 * i, 750, CCharacter.TYPE_GREEN);
        aChar.setInactive(true);
        mCharList.Add(aChar);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: This did not work, it creates 1 and breaks the loop.

Comment: Then, I don't understand your logic here. You can create bool[] array and just check filled positions in it instead of saving something in list. So, when something dragged onto unfilled string, you check character with original and if found unfilled and correct position - fill it and redraw image.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the index to skip the character

```
string[] stringArray = CMath.CharArrayToStringArray(getName().ToCharArray());
int randIndex = CMath.randomIntBetween(0, getName().Length - 1);

//create chars, if the char is the random character, skip its creation and store it to create it later on the place where the child can drag the words.
for (int i = 0; i < getName().Length; i++)
{
    if (i != randIndex)
    {
        CCharacter aChar = new CCharacter(stringArray[i], (110) + 100 * i, 750, CCharacter.TYPE_GREEN);
        aChar.setInactive(true);
        mCharList.Add(aChar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is some code that allows you to:**

- remove some chars / remove a certain percentage
- try place all occurrences of a letter

**Code:**

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var word = new Word("turtle");

            // either of these methods should be run at least once otherwise .HasWon will be true
            // hint: do that in constructor as you wish
            //word.RemoveAllOccurrencesOf('t');
            word.RemoveSomeChars();

            word.TryPlaceChar('u');
            word.TryPlaceChar('l');
            word.TryPlaceChar('e');
        }
    }

    internal class Word
    {
        private const char Separator = '_';
        private readonly char[] _chars;
        private readonly string _name;

        public char[] Chars
        {
            get { return _chars; }
        }

        public string CharsAsString
        {
            get { return new string(_chars); }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
        }

        public bool HasWon
        {
            get
            {
                return CharsAsString == Name;
            }
        }

        public Word(string name)
        {
            _name = name;
            _chars = _name.ToCharArray();
        }

        public void RemoveAllOccurrencesOf(char c)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _chars.Length; i++)
            {
                var c1 = _chars[i];
                if (c1 == c) _chars[i] = Separator;
            }
        }

        public void RemoveSomeChars(int percentage = 50)
        {
            var length = this._name.Length;
            var random = new Random();
            int count = (int)(length * (percentage / 100.0d));
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var next = random.Next(length);
                this._chars[next] = Separator;
            }
        }

        public void TryPlaceChar(char c)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < _chars.Length; i++)
            {
                if (_chars[i] == Separator && _name[i] == c)
                {
                    _chars[i] = c;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Demo:**

[image]

[image]

Now improve on that design as you see fit !

Answer (score 0):

....Create an empty string to store the value and populate it during the first skip...after you have entered the value and then prevent the skip for subsequent loops

```
string[] stringArray = CMath.CharArrayToStringArray(getName().ToCharArray());
string randChar = getName().ToCharArray()[(CMath.randomIntBetween(0, getName().Length - 1))].ToString();
string removedLetter = String.Emty;

//create chars, if the char is the random character, skip its creation and store it to create it later on the place where the child can drag the words.
for (int i = 0; i < getName().Length; i++)
{
 if (stringArray[i] != randChar || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(removedLetter))
{
 CCharacter aChar = new CCharacter(stringArray[i], (110) + 100 * i, 750, CCharacter.TYPE_GREEN);
 aChar.setInactive(true);
 mCharList.Add(aChar);
}
else
{
  removedLetter =  stringArray[i];
 }
}
```